# Production/Test Environment easy question

Tags: .net, testing, asp.net

I am working in a website that in production has only the aspx files and the bin directory and files. Any body knows how any ideas how this website was deployed I usually have my websites and I submit the code as well.

My question 2. How can I create a test website in the same server? I already create the test database.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Thanks all for you comments and participation. I think I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy only the .aspx files and bin folder contents from Visual Studio, use the menu Build > Publish > keep the checkbox checked for "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable."

This allows you to make minor changes in the .aspx files (especially the HTML) without having to recompile and redeploy the web application. You can change the .aspx files on the web server.

To create a test website on the same web server, you can just copy the entire website into a new folder and set the virtual directory in IIS.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick Respose! It's pretty clear. Now I know what to do.

Comment: Glad to help. That's why we're here.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile the asp.net application, this compiles it to an output folder with only the required files and not the code.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out how this other person publish it in to production.So you think that he compiled and then publish into production?

Comment: yes, the accepted answer was a much better explanation than mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for [configuring IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx).

When you have configured IIS, copy the source code and the binary files to the folder you specified in the configuration. You can set up multiple copies for testing if you wish - just use two different folders with a separate copy of all files in each.

Answer (score 0):

That is, of course, all you need to deploy, and you can make a test site from the same files **IF** there are not special hardcoded or dependencies.  However, if there is any configuration hard coded in the source code, you will need the source code, or you may be able to decompile the code to get source code and modify it and recompile.

Typically we deploy the same files to production and test, and that does not include "source code" like any code-behind files, and certainly not the source code of normal .NET assemblies which we share between ASP.NET and WinForms and other .NET applications.